# Using Javascript to change the method/function an HTML element calls

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, dhtml

I was wondering if its possible to use Javascript to change the function/method that an HTML element calls.

Example:

```
<input type="button" id="some_id" name="some_name" value="A Button" onclick="someFunction()" />
```

I now want to use Javascript  to change the method/function called on the `onclick` event to another function has displayed below.

```
<input type="button" id="some_id" name="some_name" value="A Button" onclick="anotherFunction()" />
```

I tried using innerHTML, and when I checked the generated HTML, it actually changed the value of the `onclick` event in the button, but when I click the button, the method is not called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a function object directly to the `onclick` field of the element. For example,

```
var inp = document.getElementById( 'some_id' );
inp.onclick = anotherFunction;
```

Comment: Define "not working." This is the standard way to assign event handlers in raw Javascript.

Comment: when assigning anotherFunction to the onclick event, it executes the function immediately, which is not what i want. i want the function be executed onclick of the element

Comment: No, it won't execute the function - be sure to copy friedo's code *exactly* as he has provided it -> that is, there is no `()` after `anotherFunction` which means you are assigning a function reference, not executing it.  +1 to this one for *not* referring to a library/framework, because I think he needs to learn the basics first.

Comment: Thx Graza, u guys are right, but this is one more thing. The new assigned function accepts two parameters. How do i get to pass the function parameters?

Comment: Got it, what i did was
    var afunc = function() //create a anonymous function
    {
       newfunction(args1, args2) //call the new function with the required parameters
    }

    element.onclick = afunc // I then assigned the reference of the anonymous functions to the onclick event of the element.

Thank u so much guys for putting me in the right path. I really appreciate.

Comment: @Index, you can save yourself a little typing by just doing `element.onclick = function() { newfunction( arg1, arg2 ); }`

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you could do:

```
$('#some_id').unbind('click');
$('#some_id').click(function () { 
    anotherFunction();
});
```

Comment: Ah, you are totally right.  You have to unbind it first.  Thanks, I hadn't realized that :)

Comment: Comment clashes - I deleted my original comment after you edited. +1 for jQuery *but* I also don't think this developer should be using it just yet - would probably be better off learning the basics first